# MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() is throwing a System.Format exception on Initialization

Tags: c#, mysql, guid

So I'm trying to use a MySqlDataReader to acquire data from my database. I know that the database does in fact respond (insert, delete, and update all work fine from my program).

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Open a connection
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select * from cs3500_u0848199.PairedGames";

            // Execute the command and cycle through the DataReader object

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                { /*do something here*/}
            }
        }
```

The problem does not appear to be with the command itself, as the command works in the MySQL workbench. Anyways, upon executing this line of code

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
```

the VS debugger notes that the following exception was thrown

> System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233033   Message=Guid should contain 32 digits with 4
>   dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithNoStyle(String guidString, GuidResult& result)
>          at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
>          at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
>          at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlGuid.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.ReadValue(MySqlPacket
>   packet, Int64 length, Boolean nullVal)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue value)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()
>          at ToDoList.BoggleService.GetBriefStatus(String gameToken) in d:\repositories\x0848199\PS11\ToDoService\BoggleService.svc.cs:line
>   443
>          at SyncInvokeGetBriefStatus(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)   InnerException:

Really unsure as to why it's telling me about the guid format since i'm not using Guids in this code.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the columns and data types of all the columns in the cs3500_u0848199.PairedGames table?

Comment: Also show the code block including the line: `BoggleService.svc.cs:line 443` and the declaration of any classes used in the call on that line

Comment: K so for columns and data types in Paired games
GameToken char(36)
Player2Token char(36)
Score1 int(11)
Score2 int(11)
Board char(16)
Duration int(11)
StartTime bigint(20)
@Ron Beyer

Comment: The code block including the line BoggleService.svc.cs:line 443 is already in my original post. Line 443 is specifically the 
while(reader.Read()) line. The relevant declarations are included in the original post, I think. If I'm mistaken please inform me as to what I'm misunderstanding. @Alex

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that it is choking on a `Guid` typed that has content that is not formatted as a `Guid`.

Comment: Yes....however since I do not have any Guids in this project I'm somewhat confused as to why it is chocking on one... @Alex

Comment: So after checking some other projects where the reader executes correctly, I've noticed that the problem appears when using the connection string that I'm using for this project. Note that the connection String I use does allow me to correctly insert/delete/update elements in the database. Any ideas as to why this might happen?

Answer (score 3):

it appears that appending `;old guids=true;` to the connection string resolved the issue.