# C# .net online connection with database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting Error "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)." while connecting to the mysql database and fetching the data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQRoh.png).

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: SO convention is to copy exception detail as text, not link to a screenshot because it is easier for us to help. Also, what is the entire connection string?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. As it stands, this question is very hard to answer. To improve your chances of getting help, please check the guidance on how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do not post image of your code, post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() is throwing a System.Format exception on Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761674/mysqlcommand-executereader-is-throwing-a-system-format-exception-on-initializa)

Comment: Please post the _full_ exception details (as text, not an image) following the instructions on this page: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @Crowcoder not only because it is easy, also because if the image gets removed from the host it becomes impossible for future people with the same issue to find out if it IS the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Connector/NET has a convention where `CHAR(36)` columns are mapped to `System.Guid` automatically. Usually this happens when reading data from a table, but it sounds like this is happening for you when calling `MySqlConnection.Open()`, which is unusual. Posting the full exception call stack may help us identify the cause.

One workaround *might* be to add `OldGuids=true` to your connection string; this will cause Connector/NET to map `CHAR(36)` as `System.String` and `BINARY(16)` as `System.Guid`. This, of course, can cause problems if you have `BINARY(16)` columns in your database that contain BLOB data.

One final option would be to switch connectors to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) and use its `GuidFormat=None` connection string option (if you want to disable all automatic Guid mapping).